# Has vs have in action/singular noun

Tags: auxiliary-verbs

Let's say I'm playing COC(clash of clans), and a clan member donated me troops.

Do I say:

> A clan member already **has** donated me troops.

Or

> A clan member already **have** donated me troops.

P.s: I'm confused now which one is correct, I think '**has**' is more correct than '**have**' but it doesn't sound right to my ear. Pls. Help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root of your sentence is

> A clan member **has**...

The subject is singular, so, your sentence would be

> A clan member **has** donated troops *to me*.

If you insist on using **have**, you might say

> Troops **have** been donated to me by a clan member.

Comment: Got it.I would never argue in this regard. 'Has' then.